# How can I open a JQuery Accordian UI tab from an external link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

#### HTML

```
<div id="accordion">


<h3>FIRST SECTION</h3>
<div>
Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus
</div>

<h3>SECOND SECTION</h3>
<div>
Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus
</div>

<h3>THIRD SECTION</h3>
<div>
Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus
</div>

</div>
```

### JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var $accordion = $("#accordion");

$accordion.accordion();

$(".opener").on("click", function () {

var $this = $(this),
    toOpen = $this.data("panel");
    $accordion.accordion("option", "active", toOpen);

    return false;
});
```

And here is the link:

```
<a class="opener" data-panel="2" href="/new-page">THIRD SECTION</a>
```

This was a solution found here: http://jsfiddle.net/VZ3T5/1/
However it obviously doesn't work when the link is coming from a separate page as the function returns false.

Does anyone know of a way to redirect to the new page, THEN accomplish the same function? I've been searching for an answer to this all over the place but nothing has worked so far. Thanks

Comment: Can you alter the external anchor to include a querystring parameter (?panelindex=2) or a page element ("#thirdsection")?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, could you provide an example of what you mean exactly?

Comment: right now the href is "/new-page".

Can you change that to either "/newpage?id=2" or "/newpage#thirdsection"?

Or something similar - a way to identify which section you need?

Comment: I've tried quite a few different strategies similar to that and none have worked so far... It just goes to the page without the tabs open.

Comment: That's because there is no way for the accordion to know which section to open.  You have to identify the section to open, which is why I was asking if you can change the link.  If you can't change the link, you'll have to solve it a different way.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is have a hash or query parameter in the URL then you can call

```
var setPanelToHashIndex = function() {
  // Alternatively for query you can use jQuery.params('panelIndex') or similar
  var hashIndex = +window.location.hash.replace('#', '')

  jQuery('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active', hashIndex)
}
```

then for doing this on page load just use `document.ready`

or `jQuery(setPanelToHashIndex)`